# Continuing a counter in an if statement

Tags: ios, if-statement, swift, counter

I'm making a stopwatch app using swift for iOS.
Making the app, so that the time is shown in seconds, wasn't a problem. Now I want to change it so that it shows the time in minutes and seconds, for example as 1:20 for 1 min 20 seconds.
To achieve the above, I did the following:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var seconds:Int = 0

@IBOutlet weak var timerOutput: UILabel!
@IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@IBAction func stopButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()

}
@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 0
    timerOutput.text = "\(seconds)"

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    timerOutput.text = "0:\(seconds)"
}
func result() {
    seconds++
    if seconds <= 60 {

        timerOutput.text = "0:\(seconds)"

    } else {
        if seconds > 60 {

            var minutes:Int = seconds/60
            var newSeconds = minutes % seconds
            timerOutput.text = "\(minutes):\(newSeconds)"
        }
    }
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app doesn't continue with the counter after the second if statement, where I define what happens after 60 seconds. I've tried a bunch of things, from using for and/or while statements to creating a completely new function for seconds > 60, but nothing seems to be working.
Currently, the app goes perfectly till 0:60, then shows 1:1, so far so good, and then doesn't do anything. It then updates every minute and shows 2:2, 3:3, 4:4 and so on.

Would appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newSeconds math should be like this:

```
// number of seconds in a minute, not the number of seconds currently
var newSeconds = seconds % 60
```

Comment: you're right, stupid mistake on my part. 
but shouldn't it be:

    var newSeconds = seconds % 60

Comment: Yes. Stupid mistake on my part :)

Comment: Yup, that was it. It works fine now, I spent more than 3 hours on such a stupid thing. Thanks anyways!